# Cannot find amitools

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby, amazon-ami

I have newly created an Amazon EC2 instance. It came with Ruby 1.8.7 which I uninstalled (with YUM) in favor of RVM and Ruby 1.9.3.

However, every time I connect to the instance via SSH I get the following error:

**`find: '/opt/aws/amitools': No such file or directory`**

Is there any way I can restore amitools (preferably without removing RVM and Ruby 1.9.3) ?

Comment: I've never had that on any of my instances, so you've presumably done something wrong.  Identify what went wrong, and it's problem solved.

Comment: @womble - no he presumably uninstalled 1.8.7 and installed 1.9.3 (like he says in the question)

Comment: Well, that would count as "something wrong" if it broke other software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /opt/aws/amitools directory contains the Amazon AWS EC2 command line utitlies for working with Amazon Machine Images (AMIs). This package is installed by default on the Amazon AMIs, but is dependent on Ruby.  By uninstalling Ruby, you uninstalled anything that depended on it as well, including this package (aws-amitools-ec2.noarch).  You can't install this package back using YUM as it will re-install the original Ruby package.

You can download the AMI Tools package from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/368/) and manually extract them into the /opt/aws/amitools directory. In my installation the tools are stored in that directory with the name ec2-VERSION, and there is a symlink called ec2 that points to this folder. [image]

You may also want the API Tools from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351/) as well, which would go into the /opt/aws/apitools directory and would have been removed by uninstalling Ruby as well.

Comment: Thanks! However `apitools` seemed to remain after I uninstalled Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

If you uninstalled 1.8.7 and just want that message to go away and don't care about amitools:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/aws/amitools
```